# calculating page size and segment size

Tags: architecture, operating-system, paging, virtual-memory

in a paged-segmented system we have the virtual address of 32 bits and 12 bits for the offset,11 bits for segment and 9 bits for page number.the how can we calculate the page size ,maximum segment size and maximum number of segment size?

Comment: More users will be willing to provide answers if you "accept" some of your past questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- 12 bits are reserved for offset, so the page size is 2^12 = 4KB
- 9 bits are reserved for page number, so each segment can contain 2^9 = 512 pages
- Each segment can grow up to size of  (# of pages) * (pages size), so maximum segment size is 512 * 4K = 2M

For more information see http://www.cs.umass.edu/~weems/CmpSci535/Discussion21.html