# Determining what segment, page, and byte a hex address is trying to access

Tags: architecture, paging, virtual-memory

So I'm reviewing for a final and I've come across a problem I can't find the solution to. I've looked through google to try and find some answers but only one thing has come up.
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927684/calculating-page-size-and-segment-size#*=*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927684/calculating-page-size-and-segment-size#_=_)

This link helped answer some of my questions but not all. Also I can't use the reference in the selected answer as I don't have access to the page. So the question I can't figure goes as follows:

Which segment, page, and byte in the page is the hex address (000A0C02) trying to access?

The only step I know to take is to convert that hex address into binary and I've done that as follows:

0000 0000 0000 1010 0000 1100 0000 0010

Can't someone point me in the direction of where I go from here? I'm not asking for the answer, I'm just looking for the formula's/steps I need to take.

Thanks

Comment: That is entirely system dependent.

Comment: No one can answer the question without knowing the segment and page size.